# Can't Install Ubuntu 14.04, tried every option in the menu

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, asus

I'm trying to install Ubuntu, my computer has the following configuration:

```
mobo Asus Maximus VI Extreme
2x Ati R9 280x (crossfire)
8gb ram
120GB kingston ssd sata
2xconventional hd, 500GB and 1000GB
```

When i try to install Ubuntu, even trying with the nomode option set, the screen goes black with a blinking line on the left upper part of the screen, and it does nothing. I've tried with older versions, but I can't install it.

Every help is appreciated, i really need to install it. Thank you!

Comment: At which point does the screen go black?

Comment: After having chose install, black screen and blinking line on the upper left side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install from Ubuntu desktop?

I have had this issue as well and the to install using:

1. Boot from install cd/usb
2. Select try Ubuntu
3. Install using the Install icon on the desktop.

If you can't try Ubuntu then the below might help.

Are you using software raid? (Using raid setup in bios) Then you need find a hardware raid controller to use instead. Linux do not like software rain in the bios.

Is your disk controllers set to use AHCI? Do so if not.
Also undo any over clocking of the system.